# select current week dates starting from saturday

Tags: mysql

> I want id whose date join is saturday to friday night.

```
SELECT id 
  FROM signup 
 WHERE yearweek(DATE(datejoin), 6) = yearweek(curdate(), 6)
```

Comment: My english is not so fluent as i would like, could you give us a better explanation about your problem?

Comment: actually i want id from last saturday to this friday night. so  what query should i write ?/

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WeekDay` function, this function returns an Integer value for every days of week from 0 for Monday to 6 for Sunday, if you subtract WeekDay from current date you will get the date of last Monday, if you want the date of the **next** Friday you can get it with a query like this :

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 4 DAY
```

In you query you want to start your week from Saturday to Friday so result of your query depends on the current day of week, if the current day of week is before Friday(from 0 to 4), you should get the date of next Friday but if current day of the week is after Friday(5 or 6) you should get the date of two Friday next !, the end of your week (Saturday) has this situation too

Look at this query, I hope it's clear enough to you :

```
SELECT id FROM signup WHERE 
datejoin BETWEEN
 (CASE
  WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) > 4 THEN
   (CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 5 DAY)
  ELSE
   (CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 2 DAY)
 END)
  AND
 (CASE
   WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) > 4 THEN
    (CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 11 DAY)
   ELSE
    (CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 4 DAY)
  END)
```

Comment: i think you gave very nice answer. but my system is going to run this query automatically on saturday..so i just want that case only.
E.g. my system is going to run query on 22 april at 12am. then data should be coming from last saturday-15april(12am) to this friday-21 april(11.59pm).

Comment: I think the query is clear and you can change it as you need, is there another problem ?

Comment: i got perfect query for my case. i have posted that as answer. u can see that.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer:

SELECT id from signup where datejoin between (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE